# SPARQL query language tag weirdness

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, sparql

This works:

```
SELECT * WHERE{
?x rdfs:label "Chalti Ka Naam Gaadi"@en .
?x foaf:name ?z .    
}
```

([Results on DBpedia SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?x%20rdfs:label%20%22Chalti%20Ka%20Naam%20Gaadi%22@en%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?x%20foaf:name%20?z%20.%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D))

This doesn't:

```
SELECT * WHERE{
?x foaf:name "Chalti Ka Naam Gaadi" .
?x rdfs:label ?z .    
}
```

([Results on DBpedia SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20*%20WHERE%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?x%20foaf:name%20%22Chalti%20Ka%20Naam%20Gaadi%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20?x%20rdfs:label%20?z%20.%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A))

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue is that plain literals with language tags: `"Chalti Ka Naam Gaadi"@en`

are not the same as plain literals without language tags: `"Chalti Ka Naam Gaadi"`

Literals are structured things made of a lexical part, language (maybe), or datatype (maybe).

You could filter: `FILTER ( str( ?name ) = "Chalti Ka Naam Gaadi")`

(`str()` returns the lexical part of the literal)

but, depending on the query engine, that will be much slower.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer on this question, since it, well, actually answers it.