# How to know if a string is a proper name of person or a place name using DBpedia?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am using SPARQL query on DBpedia into a Prolog project and I have a doubt.  I would know if a word is, most probably, a **NAME OF A PERSON** (something like: John, Mario) or a **PLACE** (like a city: Rome, London, New York).

I have implement the following two queries, the first gives me the number of persons having a specific name, and the second gives me the number of places having a specific name.

**1) Query for a PERSON NAME:**

```
select COUNT(?person) where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  { ?person foaf:givenName "John"@en }
  UNION 
  { ?person foaf:surname "John"@en }
}
```

For the name **John**, I obtain the following output: **callret-0: 7313**, so I think that it has found 7313 instances for the proper name John. Is it right?

**2) Query for a PLACE NAME:**

```
select COUNT(?place) where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place .
   { ?x rdfs:label "John"@en }
}
```

The problem is that, as you can see in the previous “place” query, I have inserted **John** as parameter, which is not a place name but a proper name of persons, but I obtain the following strange result: **callret-0: 81900104**

The problem is that, in this way, if I compare the output of the previous two queries, it seems that John is a place and not a person name!  This is not good for my scope; I have tried with other personal names and it always happens that the place query gives me a bigger output than the name query.

Why? What am I missing? Are there some errors in my queries? How can I solve it to have a correct result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, when I run the query you provided:

```
select COUNT(?place) where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place .
   { ?x rdfs:label "John"@en }
}
```

I get the result 93027312, not 81900104, but that does not really matter much.  The strange results arise because `?x` and `?place` don't have to be bound to the same thing, so you are getting all the `dbpedia-owl:Places` and counting them, but the number of result rows is the number of `dbpedia-owl:Place` *multiplied* by the number of things with `rdfs:label "John@en"`:

```
select COUNT(?place) where { ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place }
=> 646023

select COUNT(?x) where { ?x rdfs:label "John"@en }
=> 144

646023 × 144 = 93027312
```

If you actually ask for `dbpedia-owl:Place`s that have the `rdfs:label "John@en"`, you'll get no results:

```
select COUNT(?place) as ?numPlaces where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
          rdfs:label "John"@en .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+COUNT%28%3Fplace%29+as+%3FnumPlaces+where+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fplace+a+dbpedia-owl%3APlace+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%22John%22%40en+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

Also, you might consider using `dbpprop:name` instead of `rdfs:label`.  Some results seem like they are more useful that way.  For instance, let us find places called `"Springfield"`. If we ask for places with that name we get no results:

```
select * where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
          rdfs:label "Springfield"@en .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fplace+a+dbpedia-owl%3APlace+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%22Springfield%22%40en+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

However, if we modify the query and use `dbpprop:name`, we get 17.  Some of these are duplicates though, so you might have to do something else to remove duplicates.  The point, though, is that `dbpprop:name` got some results, and `rdfs:label` didn't.

```
select * where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
          dbpprop:name "Springfield"@en .
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%2a+where+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fplace+a+dbpedia-owl%3APlace+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++dbpprop%3Aname+%22Springfield%22%40en+.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)

You can even use `dbpprop:name` in working with the names of persons, although it's not as useful, because the `dbpprop:name` value for most persons is their entire name.  To find persons with the given name John using `dbpprop:name` requires a query like:

```
select * where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Person ;
          dbpprop:name ?name .
   FILTER( STRSTARTS( str( ?name ), "John" ) )
}
```

(or you could use CONTAINS instead of STRSTARTS), but this becomes *much* more expensive, because it has to select all persons and their names, and then filter through that set.  Being able to select persons based on a specific name (e.g., with `foaf:givenName`) is much more efficient.

Comment: Tnx for your clear explaination, now I will document better about SPARQL. I have understand my error but I have some problem with the query that count the number of instance of a place, this one:
select COUNT(?place) as ?numPlaces where {
   ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ;
          rdfs:label "Roma"@en .
}

As you can see if I put "Roma" as parameter the output is: numPlaces=0
If I change it and I use "Rome" the output is numPlaces=1
Why this behavior?

Comment: @AndreaNobili The `@en` is a language tag for the literal.  The English name is "Rome", not "Roma".  If you use the query `SELECT * WHERE { ?place a dbpedia-owl:Place ; rdfs:label "Roma"@it }`, you'll see one row in [the results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+*+WHERE+%7B+%3Fplace+a+dbpedia-owl%3APlace+%3B+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Roma%22%40it+%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).

Comment: @AndreaNobili As mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2015371/1281433), you can do search for strings while ignoring their language tags, but this requires a FILTER and string comparison, and is much slower.  If you're searching for strings in Italian (English), it's best to use `@it` (`@en`).