# SPARQL Matching Literals with **ANY** Language Tags without run into timeout

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

I need to select the *entity* that have a *"taxon rank (P105)"* of *"species (Q7432)"* which have a *label* that match a literal string such as "Topinambur".

I'm testing the queries on https://query.wikidata.org; 
this query goes fine and return the entity to me with satisfying response time:

```
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?entity rdfs:label "Topinambur"@de . 
  ?entity wdt:P105 wd:Q7432.
}
LIMIT 100
```

The problem here is that my requisite is **not to specify the language** but the *lexical forms* of the *labels*  in the underlying dataset ( wikidata) has **language tags** so i need a way to get **Literal Equality** for **any language**.

I tried some possible solution but I didn't find any query that didn't result in the following:
**TIMEOUT** message `com.bigdata.bop.engine.QueryTimeoutException: Query deadline is expired`

Here the list of what I tried (..and I always get TIMEOUT) :

1) based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015371/1657028) I tried:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?entity rdfs:label ?label FILTER ( str( ?label ) = "Topinambur") . 
  ?entity wdt:P105 wd:Q7432.
}
LIMIT 100
```

2) based on some other documentation I tried:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?entity wdt:P105 wd:Q7432.
  ?entity rdfs:label ?label FILTER regex(?label, "^Topinambur")  .  
}
LIMIT 100
```

3) and

```
   SELECT * WHERE {
      ?entity wdt:P105 wd:Q7432.
      ?entity rdfs:label ?label .
      FILTER langMatches( lang(?label), "*" )
      FILTER (?label = "Topinambur")
   }
   LIMIT 100
```

What I'm looking for is a performant solution or some SPARQL syntax the doesn't end up to a **TIMEOUT** message.

PS: with reference to http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt I don't understand if  `language ranges` or ```wildcards`` could help in some way.

#### EDIT

I successfully tested (without falling timeout) a similar query in **DbPedia** by using virtuoso query editor at:
https://dbpedia.org/sparql
Default Data Set Name (Graph IRI):http://dbpedia.org

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT ?resource 
WHERE { 
 ?resource rdfs:label ?label .  FILTER ( str( ?label ) = "Topinambur").
 ?resource rdf:type dbo:Species
 }
LIMIT 100
```

I am still very interested in understanding the performance problem that I experience on Wikidata and what is the best syntax to use.

Comment: What is giving the timeout? The triple store? Which triple store do you use? Is it Blazegraph or Virtuoso?

Comment: @AKSW I'm using https://query.wikidata.org ( just edited my question  thanks to your comment )   I will try asap the same on dbpedia virtuoso https://dbpedia.org/sparql but I don't know now if it's possible because of I don't know if dbpedia has the same data

Comment: @FrancoRondini, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008011/7879193). It seems something like `?entity wdt:P171+ wd:Q25314 . ` will be a suitable condition in your case.

Comment: @Stanislav Kralin you are correct! I try a couple of query resulting in  8 results in 51294ms and and 2 result in 41284ms (with DISTINCT clause) - both satisfy my requirement although not so fast. If you would to post your answer I will accept it. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP171%2B%20wd%3AQ25314%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28CONTAINS%28LCASE%28STR%28%3Flabel%29%29%2C%20%22topinambur%22%29%29%0A%7D

Comment: https://query.wikidata.org/embed.html#PREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP171%2B%20wd%3AQ25314%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20(CONTAINS(LCASE(STR(%3Flabel))%2C%20%22topinambur%22))%0A%7D

Comment: PS: due to some limitations in accepting short url in comments I posted links to my test in two separate comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008011/7879193) proposes three options:

1. Be more specific.
   The `?entity wdt:P171+ wd:Q25314` pattern seems to be sufficiently selective in your case.
2. [Wait](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T141813) until they implement full-text search.
3. Use Quarry ([example query](https://quarry.wmflabs.org/query/20483)).

---

Another option is to use Virtuoso full-text search capabilities on [wikidata.dbpedia.org](http://wikidata.dbpedia.org):

```sql
SELECT ?s WHERE { 
   ?resource rdfs:label ?label .
   ?label bif:contains "'topinambur'" .
   BIND ( IRI ( REPLACE ( STR(?resource),
                          "http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource",
                          "http://www.wikidata.org/entity"
                        )
              ) AS ?s
        )
}
```

[Try it!](http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwikidata.dbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fs+WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A+++%3Fresource+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A+++%3Flabel+bif%3Acontains+%22%27topinambur%27%22+.%0D%0A+++BIND+%28+IRI+%28+REPLACE+%28+STR%28%3Fresource%29%2C%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%22http%3A%2F%2Fwikidata.dbpedia.org%2Fresource%22%2C%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++++%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%22%0D%0A++++++++++++++++++++++++%29%0D%0A++++++++++++++%29+AS+%3Fs%0D%0A++++++++%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

---

It seems that even the query below sometime works on wikidata.dbpedia.org without falling into timeout:

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?resource WHERE { 
   ?resource rdfs:label ?label .
   FILTER ( STR(?label) = "Topinambur" ) .
}
```

[Try it!](http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwikidata.dbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fresource+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B+%0D%0A+%3Fresource+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+.%0D%0A+FILTER+%28+str%28+%3Flabel+%29+%3D+%22Topinambur%22%29.%0D%0A+%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=120000&debug=on)

---

Two hours ago I've [removed](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q161378&type=revision&diff=525469111&oldid=517170029) this statement on Wikidata:

```
wd:Q161378 rdfs:label "topinambur"@ru .
```

I'm not a botanist, but 'topinambur' is definitely not a word in [Russian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet).

Comment: ...actually It was really a strange case that the name ( label ) Topinambur referred  'Dioscorea communis' (Q161378)  where in many other languages it is referred  to Helianthus tuberosus (Q146190)

Answer (score 3):

I solved similar problem - want to find entity with label string in any language. I recommend do not use FILTER, because it is too slow. Rather use UNION like this:

```
SELECT ?entity WHERE {
  ?entity wdt:P105 wd:Q7432.
  { ?entity rdfs:label "Topinambur"@de . }
  UNION { ?entity rdfs:label "Topinambur"@en . }
  UNION { ?entity rdfs:label "Topinambur"@fr . }
}
GROUP BY ?entity
LIMIT 100
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fentity%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fentity%20wdt%3AP105%20wd%3AQ7432.%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fentity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Topinambur%22%40de%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%20%7B%20%3Fentity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Topinambur%22%40en%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20UNION%20%7B%20%3Fentity%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Topinambur%22%40fr%20.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fentity%0ALIMIT%20100%20)

This solution is not perfect, because you have to enumater all languages, but is fast and reliable. List of all available wikidata language are [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Wikimedia_language_codes/lists/all).

Answer (score 0):

Working further on from @quick's answer, and showing it for lexemes rather than labels. First identifying relevant language codes:

```
SELECT (GROUP_CONCAT(?mword; separator=" ") AS ?mwords) {
  BIND(1 AS ?dummy)
  VALUES ?word { "topinambur" }
  {
    SELECT (COUNT(?lexeme) AS ?count) ?language_code {
      ?lexeme dct:language / wdt:P424 ?language_code .
    }
    GROUP BY ?language_code
    HAVING (?count > 100)
    ORDER BY DESC(?count)
  }
  BIND(CONCAT('"', ?word, '"@', ?language_code) AS ?mword)
}
GROUP BY ?dummy
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3Fmword%3B%20separator%3D%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fmwords%29%20%7B%0A%20%20BIND%281%20AS%20%3Fdummy%29%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fword%20%7B%20%22topinambur%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28COUNT%28%3Flexeme%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20%3Flanguage_code%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flexeme%20dct%3Alanguage%20%2F%20wdt%3AP424%20%3Flanguage_code%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Flanguage_code%0A%20%20%20%20HAVING%20%28%3Fcount%20%3E%20100%29%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fcount%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20BIND%28CONCAT%28%27%22%27%2C%20%3Fword%2C%20%27%22%40%27%2C%20%3Flanguage_code%29%20AS%20%3Fmword%29%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fdummy%0A)

Followed by the verbose query

```
SELECT (COUNT(?lexeme) AS ?count) ?language (GROUP_CONCAT(?word; separator=" ") AS ?words) {
  VALUES ?word { "topinambur"@eo "topinambur"@ko "topinambur"@bfi "topinambur"@nl "topinambur"@uk "topinambur"@cy "topinambur"@pt "topinambur"@zh "topinambur"@br "topinambur"@bg "topinambur"@ms "topinambur"@tg "topinambur"@se "topinambur"@ta "topinambur"@non "topinambur"@it "topinambur"@zh-min-nan "topinambur"@nan "topinambur"@fi "topinambur"@jbo "topinambur"@ml "topinambur"@ja "topinambur"@ku "topinambur"@bn "topinambur"@ar "topinambur"@nb "topinambur"@es "topinambur"@pl "topinambur"@nn "topinambur"@sk "topinambur"@da "topinambur"@de "topinambur"@cs "topinambur"@fr "topinambur"@sv "topinambur"@eu "topinambur"@he "topinambur"@la "topinambur"@en "topinambur"@ru }
  ?lexeme dct:language ?language ;
          ontolex:lexicalForm / ontolex:representation ?word .
}
GROUP BY ?language
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%28COUNT%28%3Flexeme%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20%3Flanguage%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28%3Fword%3B%20separator%3D%22%20%22%29%20AS%20%3Fwords%29%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fword%20%7B%20%22topinambur%22%40eo%20%22topinambur%22%40ko%20%22topinambur%22%40bfi%20%22topinambur%22%40nl%20%22topinambur%22%40uk%20%22topinambur%22%40cy%20%22topinambur%22%40pt%20%22topinambur%22%40zh%20%22topinambur%22%40br%20%22topinambur%22%40bg%20%22topinambur%22%40ms%20%22topinambur%22%40tg%20%22topinambur%22%40se%20%22topinambur%22%40ta%20%22topinambur%22%40non%20%22topinambur%22%40it%20%22topinambur%22%40zh-min-nan%20%22topinambur%22%40nan%20%22topinambur%22%40fi%20%22topinambur%22%40jbo%20%22topinambur%22%40ml%20%22topinambur%22%40ja%20%22topinambur%22%40ku%20%22topinambur%22%40bn%20%22topinambur%22%40ar%20%22topinambur%22%40nb%20%22topinambur%22%40es%20%22topinambur%22%40pl%20%22topinambur%22%40nn%20%22topinambur%22%40sk%20%22topinambur%22%40da%20%22topinambur%22%40de%20%22topinambur%22%40cs%20%22topinambur%22%40fr%20%22topinambur%22%40sv%20%22topinambur%22%40eu%20%22topinambur%22%40he%20%22topinambur%22%40la%20%22topinambur%22%40en%20%22topinambur%22%40ru%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Flexeme%20dct%3Alanguage%20%3Flanguage%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ontolex%3AlexicalForm%20%2F%20ontolex%3Arepresentation%20%3Fword%20.%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Flanguage%0A)

For querying on labels, do something similar to:

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) ?language (GROUP_CONCAT(?word; separator=" ") AS ?words) {
  VALUES ?word { "topinambur"@eo "topinambur"@ko "topinambur"@bfi "topinambur"@nl "topinambur"@uk "topinambur"@cy "topinambur"@pt "topinambur"@zh "topinambur"@br "topinambur"@bg "topinambur"@ms "topinambur"@tg "topinambur"@se "topinambur"@ta "topinambur"@non "topinambur"@it "topinambur"@zh-min-nan "topinambur"@nan "topinambur"@fi "topinambur"@jbo "topinambur"@ml "topinambur"@ja "topinambur"@ku "topinambur"@bn "topinambur"@ar "topinambur"@nb "topinambur"@es "topinambur"@pl "topinambur"@nn "topinambur"@sk "topinambur"@da "topinambur"@de "topinambur"@cs "topinambur"@fr "topinambur"@sv "topinambur"@eu "topinambur"@he "topinambur"@la "topinambur"@en "topinambur"@ru }
  ?item rdfs:label ?word ;
}
GROUP BY ?language
```