# getting label of a property from a large query takes much longer and timeout

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Let's say I want to retrieve the "sex or gender" (`P21`) of all people (i.e. human = `Q5`) that has an IMDb ID (`P345`) from Wikidata

I could get the total list which is nearly 444k lines in less than 20 seconds with the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?imdb ?gender WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
  wdt:P345 ?imdb;
  wdt:P21 ?gender.
}
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fimdb%20%3Fgender%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%3B%0A%20%20wdt%3AP345%20%3Fimdb%3B%0A%20%20wdt%3AP21%20%3Fgender.%0A%7D)

but if I want the **English gender label** ("male" instead of `Q6581097`) in my results, the **request takes too long and fail** with a "`Query timeout limit reached`"

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?imdb ?gender ?genderLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
  wdt:P345 ?imdb;
  wdt:P21 ?gender.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

[try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3Fimdb%20%3Fgender%20%3FgenderLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5%3B%0A%20%20wdt%3AP345%20%3Fimdb%3B%0A%20%20wdt%3AP21%20%3Fgender.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)

Q: Is there a way to optimize the query so that getting the corresponding value (joining) of a Property doesn't take much longer to compute?

I've tried to filter the label gender in English (which BTW might have been the case) as explained [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/query_optimization/hy) without much result

```
?gender rdfs:label ?genderLabel. FILTER( LANG(?genderLabel)="en" )
```

and I've also tried to be more specific as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44999328/fuzzy-entity-query-in-wikidata-with-sparql-times-out/45008011#45008011) with the following:

```
  ?item wdt:P31+ wd:Q5;
```

but this is the a plain 1-to-1 mapping of property (no fuzzy)

NB: as of today there is about 30 different `P21` (gender) properties for the 443851 lines

Comment: Try https://w.wiki/78Bg